# pylint plugin to warn of specific function use?

Tags: python, pylint

I want to have a pylint (or possibly mypy?) plugin to warn if a specific function is used. More to the point, I want to warn when a dictionary is accessed using the brackets operator instead of the get method:

```
mydict = { "foo": 3 }

# warning: direct dictionary access
mydict["bar"]

# no warning:
mydict.get("bar", None)
```

With the official docs, I managed to figure out that I have to implement a *checker* that overrides `visit_subscript`. However, inside `visit_subscript`, I don't have access to the type of the left-hand side, so I cannot determine if a `Dict` is being accessed or, say, a `List`, and I don't want warnings for those.

Is there a way to get the inferred type (if available) for the subscript in pylint? Or is there an alternative way to write such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to `node`, and `node.value` points to what is being subscripted. You can check directly if it's an instance of `nodes.Dict` to catch dict literals. For other types like `nodes.Name` or `nodes.Call`, you can use `utils.safe_infer()` to try to see if the inferred value is a dictionary. See a model in `TypeChecker.visit_subscript()`.